# Jquery change disabled button when form is send

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, disabled-input

I have a button which have to be visable only if form is valid.
I write this:

```
function submit_form(){
var('#button2').attr('disabled',true);
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    data : $('#formset').serialize(),
    success : function(json) {
        console.log(json);
        console.log("form sent!");
    },
    $('#button2').attr('disabled', false);
    error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        console.log('error occured');
    }
});
```

}
but it doesn't work. Where is an error?

Comment: Error in this variable declaration: `var('#button2').attr('disabled',true);`

Answer (score 1):

Just you need to change `prop`

Use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Here it seems to error on first line `var('#button2')`

```
function submit_form(){
$('#button2').prop('disabled',true);
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    data : $('#formset').serialize(),
    success : function(json) {
        console.log(json);
        console.log("form sent!");
       $('#button2').prop('disabled', false);
    },

    error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        console.log('error occured');
    }
});
```

Comment: I update my code, in console I can see "form sent!", but the button is still disabled...

Comment: you need to enable the buttion @kaja once form sent ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put the button into the success function ?

```
function submit_form(){
var('#button2').attr('disabled',true);
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    data : $('#formset').serialize(),
    success : function(json) {
        console.log(json);
        console.log("form sent!");
        $('#button2').attr('disabled', false);
    },

    error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        console.log('error occured');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   function submit_form(){
var('#button2').attr('disabled',true);
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    data : $('#formset').serialize(),
    success : function(json) {
        console.log(json);
        console.log("form sent!");
    $("#button2").attr("disabled",false);
//  $("#button2").prop("disabled",false);
// can use prop instead of attr

},
    error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        console.log('error occured');
    }
});
```

Comment: Mind explain a bit more ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

You should enable button always whether ajax request was successfully completed or not.

```
function submit_form() {
   $('#button2').prop('disabled',true);
   $.ajax({
       type : "POST",
       data : $('#formset').serialize(),
       success : function(json) {
          console.log(json);
          console.log("form sent!");
       },

       error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
          console.log('error occured');
       },

       complete: function () {
        $('#button2').prop('disabled', false);
       }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunatelly... Can the reaseon be in html?                                    <a href="{% url 'shortages:email_formal' pk=case.pk %}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="button2" role="button">